# Unhandled SyntaxKind: Unknown error after upgrading TypeScript to version 5.0.4 for Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to upgrade from Angular 15(Typescript 4.8.4) to Angular 16(Typescript 5.0.4) and when trying to start the application this error breaks the build.

I have tried looking through the typescript.js to see if I can find which node.kind value is wrong/missing but as far as I can see they all seem to exist.

Error:

```
HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:110792
      Debug.fail(`Unhandled SyntaxKind: ${Debug.formatSyntaxKind(node.kind)}.`);
            ^
Error: Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: Unknown.
    at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:110792:13)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:110333:9)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:114112:7)
    at pipelineEmit (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:110282:7)
    at emit (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:110250:7)
    at emitInterfaceDeclaration (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:112197:7)
    at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:110517:20)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:110333:9)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:114112:7)
    at pipelineEmit (HOMEFOLDER\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:110282:7)
```

I can see the line that is generating the error is

```
printer.printNode(ts.EmitHint.Unspecified, interface_, resultFile);
```

This itself is part of this function where ***ts*** is ***typescript***

```
function interfaceToString(interface_: any) {
  const resultFile = ts.createSourceFile('someFileName.ts', '', ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, /*setParentNodes*/ false, ts.ScriptKind.TS);
  const printer = ts.createPrinter({
    newLine: ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed,
  });
  return printer.printNode(ts.EmitHint.Unspecified, interface_, resultFile);
}
```

The ***interface_*** passed in is this

```
NodeObject {
  pos: -1,
  end: -1,
  flags: 8,
  modifierFlagsCache: 0,
  transformFlags: 1,
  parent: undefined,
  kind: 261,
  symbol: undefined,
  localSymbol: undefined,
  modifiers: undefined,
  name: [
    TokenObject {
      pos: -1,
      end: -1,
      flags: 8,
      modifierFlagsCache: 0,
      transformFlags: 0,
      parent: undefined,
      kind: 93
    }
  ],
  typeParameters: IdentifierObject {
    pos: -1,
    end: -1,
    flags: 8,
    modifierFlagsCache: 0,
    transformFlags: 0,
    parent: undefined,
    kind: 79,
    escapedText: 'FormInterface',
    jsDoc: undefined,
    flowNode: undefined,
    symbol: undefined
  },
  heritageClauses: undefined,
  members: [ pos: -1, end: -1, hasTrailingComma: false, transformFlags: 0 ],
  jsDoc: undefined
}
resultFile SourceFileObject {
  pos: 0,
  end: 0,
  flags: 0,
  modifierFlagsCache: 0,
  transformFlags: 0,
  parent: undefined,
  kind: 308,
  statements: [ pos: 0, end: 0, hasTrailingComma: false, transformFlags: 0 ],
  endOfFileToken: TokenObject {
    pos: 0,
    end: 0,
    flags: 0,
    modifierFlagsCache: 0,
    transformFlags: 0,
    parent: undefined,
    kind: 1
  },
  text: '',
  fileName: 'someFileName.ts',
  path: '',
  resolvedPath: '',
  originalFileName: '',
  languageVersion: 99,
  languageVariant: 0,
  scriptKind: 3,
  isDeclarationFile: false,
  hasNoDefaultLib: false,
  locals: undefined,
  nextContainer: undefined,
  endFlowNode: undefined,
  nodeCount: 2,
  identifierCount: 0,
  symbolCount: 0,
  parseDiagnostics: [],
  bindDiagnostics: [],
  bindSuggestionDiagnostics: undefined,
  lineMap: undefined,
  externalModuleIndicator: undefined,
  setExternalModuleIndicator: [Function: setExternalModuleIndicator],
  pragmas: Map(0) {},
  checkJsDirective: undefined,
  referencedFiles: [],
  typeReferenceDirectives: [],
  libReferenceDirectives: [],
  amdDependencies: [],
  commentDirectives: undefined,
  identifiers: Map(0) {},
  packageJsonLocations: undefined,
  packageJsonScope: undefined,
  imports: undefined,
  moduleAugmentations: undefined,
  ambientModuleNames: undefined,
  resolvedModules: undefined,
  classifiableNames: undefined,
  impliedNodeFormat: undefined
}
```